# C++: libpng conflict on opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, libpng

I'm trying to read a png file using opencv2, I get the following error.

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.53 but running with 1.6.27
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0)) in resize, file /home/dpk/Desktop/opencv/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3484
```

I have `libpng 1.6.27` on my system. 
Opencv was built using the command `cmake -D BUILD_PNG=OFF /home/dpk/Desktop/opencv`, to avoid conflict between the library from opencv and the one in my system.

I compile the program which needs to read png as below

```
g++ preProcess.cpp -I/usr/local/include/libpng16 `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -o preProcess
```

The output of `ldd` on the binary gives the following for libpng

```
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: When I look at the 3rdparty directory in the repo, even in 2010 there was a version of LibPNG newer than 1.2.53, so it would seem that's not where that came from. Do you happen to have some other copy of OpenCV installed on your system, that it accidentally uses? Does the output of `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from OpenCV's `CMakeLists.txt`, you had to set `WITH_PNG=OFF`, not `BUILD_PNG`.

Comment: Wouldn't that completely disable PNG support in OpenCV? That doesn't seem very desirable, considering the user wants to "read a png file using opencv2"...

Comment: I've got impression it is exactly what asker wants. You can't, of course, have support for PNG without linking to a library, but I think asker uses libpng in his app directly, not through OpenCV.